# Data container with numeric field names

Tags: python, namedtuple, python-dataclasses, data-containers

Is there a way in python to create a data container with numeric field names?

A minimal example: I have variables called `beta0`, `beta1`, `beta2` and would like to pack them into a container `beta` and access them by `beta.0`, `beta.1`, `beta.2`.

I checked `recordclass`, `namedtuple`, and `dataclass`, but none of them allows this.

EDIT: What is the best practice in python for treating a bunch of related parametres?

Answer (score 1):

you could simply use a dictionary and access them.

```
beta={0: beta0, 1: beta1, 2: beta2}
```

Access them with

```
beta[0]
beta[1]
...
```

If you need to use the numeric value as variable you can also do this by indexing: eg.

```
for num in range(3):
    print(beta[num])
```

Comment: I'd add that a number following a dot is not valid syntax, so a custom class with the exact semantics desired can not be created. But indeed, a dictionary is the obvious thing to use, unless all numeric keys exist  in a contiguous range starting in 0  - in that case, just use a list.